# ByteBuffer allocate as first - little endian

Tags: java, android

What to do to get a number in bytes array first, e.g .:
\xb6\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00

```
byte[] totalChunksData = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putInt(182).array();
result: \x00\x00\x00\xb6\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)` method:

```
byte[] totalChunksData = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(182).array();
```